# Stripe Card Retrieval - PaymentMethodService vs CardService

Tags: stripe-payments

Using the Stripe CLI to create subscriptions for users, I noticed I can successfully retrieve their credit card details to display (such as last 4, date etc) by leveraging the following code snippet:

```
 var service = new CardService();
             
            var cardOptions = new CardListOptions
            {
                Limit = 3 
            };
            var cards = await service.ListAsync(StripeCustomerId, cardOptions);
```

However, testing with a WordPress plugin to make one charge to a new customer (so not a subscription, but rather a single charge), the above code returns no credit cards!

I then tried this bit of code:

```
  var paymentMethodService = new PaymentMethodService();
            var pmList = paymentMethodService.List(new PaymentMethodListOptions { Customer = StripeCustomerId,
            Type = "card"});
```

and it returned my user's credit card metadata successfully for the single charge. I then tried this code against my subscription users, and it also worked successfully!

This leads me to the conclusion that if I want to reliably and guaranteed get credit card details from a user, that I should use the second snippet above.

..But this begs the question - what is the difference between CardService and PaymentMethodService? If I want to solve the problem of "How can I show all of the credit cards that a user has to them on their billing page in my custom web application", which service do I use?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use the PaymentMethodService.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods

For historical reasons, there are a few different object types in Stripe's API for representing cards (the [Card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object) object with an ID `card_xxxx` , the [Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/object) object with ID `src_xxxx` and `type:card` and now [PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) with an ID `pm_xxx`). They're all slightly different and differently shaped. Cards and Sources are essentially deprecated though.

PaymentMethods replaces all of them and is fully backwards compatible; for example if you used the Card object in the past and saved those to customers, you can use PaymentMethodService.list to get both those Card objects(and any Source or PaymentMethods) returned, and they are returned shaped as PaymentMethods via a compatibility layer. That means your code doesn't need to think about the differences in the underlying objects and you can use PaymentMethodService as the canonical way to work with a customer's saved cards.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning#compatibility

> However, testing with a WordPress plugin to make one charge to a new customer (so not a subscription, but rather a single charge), the above code returns no credit cards!

Thats probably because the WordPress plugin creates PaymentMethods, or it creates Sources, depending on when it was written. So you won't get those returned using CardService, but if you use PaymentMethodService, you will, because of that compatibility layer, so it's the perfect example of why you should use it here and it's the canonical way to use Stripe going forward.